# If $x^2+y^2 = 1$ then what is the maximum value of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: geometry, optimization

If $x^2+y^2 = 1$ then what is the maximum value of $x$ and $y$? How many methods can be used to solve for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: This is the formula for a circle.

Comment: It would be much more interesting to read "and" as "+" and thus ask "What is the maximum value of $x+y$.

Comment: For univariate equations, desmos.com is a great graphing tool! It's free and perfect for conic sections.

Comment: The answer must be $42$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How!!!Please....

Comment: graph it, $ + 1$ for x and y each

Comment: @YvesDaoust A hearty glass of pan galactic gargleblaster to you Sir!

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$, and $1-y^2$ is maximum for $y=0$, hence $x=1$.
- the equation is equivalent to $x=\cos\theta,y=\sin\theta$; the maximum occurs at $\theta=0$.
- set $u=x^2,v=y^2$ and maximize $u$ under constraints $u,v\ge0$ by linear programming.
- $x+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$ is maximized when$1+2\lambda x=0,2\lambda y=0,x^2+y^2=1$ hence $y=0$.
- $x^2=1-y^2$ so that $x^2\le 1$ and equality can be achieved.
- this circle has "axis" length $1$ and has "vertexes" in all directions. $x=1$ is one.
- $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-2y$ cancels for $y=0$, then $x=\pm 1$.
- the domains of the functions $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ are both $[-1,1]$.
- the real part is smaller than the modulus $x<\sqrt{zz^*}=1$, but for a real number.

... and $33$ others. All arguments can be repeated with $x$ and $y$ swapped.

Comment: Wow, nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that both $x^2$ and $y^2$ can never be negative. But they have have to add up to $+1$. So clear that $x^2=1$ and $y^2=0$ is an extreme case (and vice versa). This means $x=\pm1,y=0$ and $x=0,y=\pm1$ are the only possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2+y^2=1$ is the equation of a circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$. The maximum value of $x$ is $x=1$, and the maximum value of y is $y=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The mosquito-nuking solution: with Lagrange multipliers.

Find the extrema of $f(x,y) = x$ with restriction $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
$$1 = 2\lambda x,$$
$$0 = 2\lambda y.$$
The second equation $\implies$ $y = 0$ $\implies$ $x =\pm 1$.